# DefaultRolloverStrategy does not delete any file

Tags: log4j2

I used the following Log4j2 configuration to test the behavior. It rotates the file every 10 seconds and should keep only 3 files. However no file is deleted. What am I missing?

Please don't suggest to use the delete action.

```
<RollingFile name="File" fileName="/var/log/mylog.log" filePattern="/var/log/mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="10"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but I had the same problem.

I also realise the OP said `"Please don't suggest to use the delete action"` so this may mean there are version restrictions on using `Delete`.

However I found this [feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-435) which sheds some light on this behaviour - a comment there indicates.

> DefaultRolloverStrategy max attribute only applies if you have a %i in
>   the file pattern.

The [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender), under "Default Rollover Strategy", indicates

> The default rollover strategy accepts both a date/time pattern and an
>   integer from the filePattern attribute specified on the
>   RollingFileAppender itself

and

> max   : integer :  "The maximum value of the counter. Once this values is
>   reached older archives will be deleted on subsequent rollovers. The
>   default value is 7."

A bit a mix of "counter" and "integer" - but think (now) that it means this only applies to "%i" pattern.  If the manual used "integer counter" it may be clearer.

A solution I got working (using 2.10.0 and days rather than seconds) using `Delete` (sorry OP) was:

```
<RollingFile name="MyLog" fileName="${sys:dataDir}/mylog.log" append="true">
    <FilePattern>./mylog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</FilePattern>
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg %logger{36}%n"/>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        <Delete basePath="${sys:dataDir}" maxDepth="1">
            <IfFileName glob="mylog-*.log.zip" />
            <IfLastModified age="7d" />
        </Delete>
    </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
</RollingFile >
```